# Preventing NaN when dividing zero with value

Tags: floating-point, d, nan

I'm writing a 3D game using OpenGL in D and I'm having trouble with floating points. When I divide zero with another float value (non zero) it will always be NaN rather than 0. This is causing troubles sense the NaN will propagate throughout the code sense everything else that is divided/multiplied with it also becomes NaN. I really don't want to wrap all my divisions with a `if value != 0.0f` check.

A simple check like `float value = getCurrentSpeed() / getMaxSpeed()` will return NaN if `getCurrentSpeed()` return 0.0f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dividing, say `x / y`, you can get *four* outcomes (providing that neither `x` nor `y` is `NaN, +Inf, Inf`):

```
     0   when            y != 0 -- <- expected
  +Inf        x > 0  and y == 0
  -Inf        x < 0  and y == 0 
   NaN        x == 0 and y == 0 -- <- actual
```

So in your case - `NaN` when computing

```
  float value = getCurrentSpeed() / getMaxSpeed()
```

we can conclude that *both* `getCurrentSpeed()` and `getMaxSpeed()` are *zeros* and you have to test `getMaxSpeed()` for being `0`

Comment: It seems that the problem origin is in an external library where the length of a vector is calculates as NaN when it should be zero.