# Problem with -nan(ind) when i print in unreal engine 4

Tags: c++, patch, unreal-engine4, chunks

i'm trying to make a chunk download system in Unreal Engine 4.27.2, but i've no c++ knowledge, i'm just follow this tutorial, the time he start to code the specific part is 10mins (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zd6uir0SFHo) to make the system, but for some reason, i have not the same results in one of my codes... The error i'm is exactly when i print the percentage of download and mount process it prints:

Loading process: -nan(ind)
Mount Process: -nan(ind)

My code:

```
void UPatchingGameInstance::GetLoadingProgress(int32& BytesDownloaded, int32& TotalBytesToDownload, float& DownloadPercent, int32& ChunksMounted, int32& TotalChunksToMount, float& MountPercent) const
{
    TSharedRef<FChunkDownloader> Downloader = FChunkDownloader::GetChecked();

    FChunkDownloader::FStats LoadingStats = Downloader->GetLoadingStats();

    BytesDownloaded = LoadingStats.BytesDownloaded;
    TotalBytesToDownload = LoadingStats.TotalBytesToDownload;

    ChunksMounted = LoadingStats.ChunksMounted;
    TotalChunksToMount = LoadingStats.TotalChunksToMount;

    DownloadPercent = ((float)BytesDownloaded / (float)TotalBytesToDownload) * 100.0f;
    MountPercent = ((float)ChunksMounted / (float)TotalChunksToMount) * 100.0f;
}
```

The Blueprint part:

[image: Blueprint part of project, to show how i made the print string on Gamemode]

Comment: What are the values of `TotalBytesToDownload`, `TotalChunksToMount` and the other variables?

Comment: TotalBytes is the total Bytes of the archives i've to download and TotalChunksToMount is the total number of parts to mount after download all the archives, every "chunk" is a part of the game to download as an archive .pak. I'm doing this for a game of meta quest 2. And the chunks is to separate the assets, to help in future changes in the assets.

Comment: What I meant was if you ever checked if [one of more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33756972/preventing-nan-when-dividing-zero-with-value) of those values are equal to zero.

Comment: Well, i dont check this, but in fact is this a problem if the values are equal to zero, when i test i back asap with the results, but for now, thanks!